# Multi-column duplicates query

Tags: c#, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I'm using t-sql from csharp to query a database table that contains 5 columns of 
integers which tracks the number of times certain actions have taken place in a 
program. There are also other columns in the table.

Example:

```
Num1  Num2  Num3  Num4  Num5

1     15    22     23    32
15    4     21     17    19
6     5     15     18    20
```

I need to construct a query that returns each duplicated set of integers and a 
count of all rows where all of these 5 columns, when considered as a set of values, have been duplicated.

To clarify further, I need to know how many times Num1=6, Num2=5, Num3=15, Num4=18, and Num5=20, if it does occur. I also need to know if any other sets of duplicates occur in these five columns.

I know some SQL, but this is a complex query that I need help with. I've tried 
many subqueries etc, but I just can't figure out the right combination of
SELECT and ORDER BY's to make it work. The data table in question has about 7000 
records in it and is expected to grow no larger than about 10k, so performance is secondary.

THANKS in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with a join on a subquery, which takes only duplicates and count them

```
select a.Col1, a.Col2, a.Col3, a.Num1, a.Num2, a.Num3, a.Num4, a.Num5, t.cnt as numberOfDuplicates
from tableA a
join (select Num1, Num2, Num3, Num4, Num5, count(*) as cnt
      from tableA
      group by Num1, Num2, Num3, Num4, Num5
      having count(*) > 1
     ) t
  on a.Num1 = t.Num1 and a.Num2 = t.Num2 and a.Num3 = t.Num3 and a.Num4 = t.Num4 and a.Num5 = t.Num5
```

Comment: OK now THIS looks like something I never would have thought of. Thanks, I will go study the Having keyword.

Answer (score 1):

This looks like a straight-forward SELECT COUNT with a GROUP BY on the five columns.

Something along the lines of:

```
SELECT Num1, Num2, Num3, Num4, Num5, COUNT(someColumn) GROUP BY Num1, Num2, Num3, Num4, Num5
```

Comment: Sorry I don't understand your answer. I tried the following based on your comment: 'SELECT Num1, Num2, Num3, Num4, Num5 FROM [TableName] GROUP BY Num1, Num2, Num3, Num4, Num5' but this seems to return all rows where duplicates do NOT occur. I also received an error when I put the COUNT clause in. I don't get what you mean by (somecolumn). Could you explain?

Comment: In `someColumn`, you're supposed to put in the name of some column in your table. (You did mention it had other columns, but even if it didn't, I think any of the Num columns would work as well.)

Comment: I just tried it again. As mentioned, when I leave the COUNT clause in the query I receive an error stating Invalid Object Name 'COUNT'.